# Add column from one dataframe to another matching values in two columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have been struggling with this for a few hours and need to get this solved in a hurry due to deadline.

table1 has format

| Name | Date1 | Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | d1 | val1 |
| B | d2 | val2 |
| B | d3 | val3 |
| C | d4 | val4 |

table2 has format

| Name | Date2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | d1 |
| B | d2 |
| B | d3 |
| C | d4 |

I want to add Column from table 1 to table 2 based on the matching condition where table1 Name = table2 Name and Date1 = Date2.

I normally do this using the match() function but only in the case when I am matching one column value with another. How can I do it for two?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try` merge()`?

Comment: Please look at `?merge` or the join functions in package `dplyr` _e.g._ `inner_join`. Or search here: this question has been answered many times.